# Unable to install 'mysqlclient' on linux shared hosting server. 'Failed to build wheel for mysqlclient'

Tags: python, django, linux, mysql-connector

I have locally developed a Django App **(django version - 3.0.5, python version 3.8.2, OS - Windows 10)**.
On my local server I installed 'mysqlclient' using the below command.

```
python -m pip install mysqlclient
```

The app is fully functioning on my local server. I purchased a shared hosting for the production deployment. It is a **linux server(django version - 3.0.5, python version 3.7.3**). I installed Django and Python on virtualenv but am unable to install 'mysqlclient'. I used the below command.

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

It showed the error below:

```
$ pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.4.6.tar.gz (85 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/testdev/virtualenv/test/3.7/bin/python3.7_bin -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l6dot083/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l6dot083/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-y99lbq6b
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-l6dot083/mysqlclient/
  Complete output (34 lines):
  /bin/mysql_config: line 8: rpm: command not found
  /bin/mysql_config: line 8: rpm: command not found
  /bin/mysql_config: line 8: rpm: command not found
  /bin/mysql_config: line 8: rpm: command not found
  /opt/alt/python37/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
  unable to execute 'gcc': Permission denied
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/testdev/virtualenv/test/3.7/bin/python3.7_bin -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l6dot083/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l6dot083/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-1a81g6q6/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/testdev/virtualenv/test/3.7/include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-l6dot083/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (34 lines):
    /bin/mysql_config: line 8: rpm: command not found
    /bin/mysql_config: line 8: rpm: command not found
    /bin/mysql_config: line 8: rpm: command not found
    /bin/mysql_config: line 8: rpm: command not found
    /opt/alt/python37/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    unable to execute 'gcc': Permission denied
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/testdev/virtualenv/test/3.7/bin/python3.7_bin -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l6dot083/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l6dot083/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-1a81g6q6/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/testdev/virtualenv/test/3.7/include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried below scenarios as solusions but didn't work.

- upgrade 'pip' version
- upgrage 'wheel' version
- tried to install package via Github
- `pip install MySQL-python` and got (ModuleNotFoundError)
- `pip3 install MySQL-python` and got the same error

(**Note**: 'sudo' or 'apt' commands are not working).

I'm not permitted to use an unofficial mysqlclient package.

What is the solution for this issue?

Alternatively how to connect my app with the database without the mysqlclient package?

Comment: you can see for the log `unable to execute 'gcc': Permission denied` , try running with sudo,  `sudo python -m pip install mysqlclient` or `sudo pip install mysqlclient`  but take  with wich python version pip is using

Comment: 'sudo' not working. python version 3.7.3 on server, django version 3.0.5 on server. I used pip3 command as well.

Comment: what problem do you get when you run with sudo ? problem seems clear to me, you don't have permissions to run gcc -> `unable to execute 'gcc': Permission denied`

Comment: download msbuild  or gcc with a PATH emtry, stragely mine asked for msbuild on win 10 64

Comment: when I run sudo it says 
'[testdev@ultrawp test]$ sudo
jailshell: sudo: command not found'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by the service provider. They were able to install mysqlclient using their admin privileges.